# Saving result of nested list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to store intermediate results from a nested list comprehension in sublists so that the result looks like this:

```
example_list = [[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]], [[2,3,4], [2,3,4]]];
sink = [];

for sl in example_list :

   temp = [];

   for ssl in sl :

       temp.append(np.mean(ssl));

   sink.append(temp);

expected_result = [[2,2], [3,3]];
```

How do you perform this using a list comprehension?

I tried something like this, but obviously it doesn't work, I'm blocked on the syntax:

```
sink = [[np.mean(j)] for i in example_list for j in i];
```

Comment: why all the `;`?

Comment: Well do write a nested list comprehension.

Comment: `[[np.mean(ssl) for ssl in sl] for sl in example_list]`?

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect !

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the challenge is. You can create a nested loop within the list. comprehension and store the values.

Here's what I did:

```
x = [[[i*j*k for i  in range (1,4)] for j in range(1,4)] for k in range(1,3)]
print (x)
```

Output is:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6], [3, 6, 9]], [[2, 4, 6], [4, 8, 12], [6, 12, 18]]]
```

If you can give me a good use case, it can be implemented.

In the meanwhile, let me see if I can grab some data and show you the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this;

```
final_list=[[int(np.mean(ssl)) for ssl in sl] for sl in example_list]
print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[[2, 2], [3, 3]]
```